# Binary Serialization in VB6?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, vb6

In C# I open a MemoryStream and use the BinaryFormatter to serialize an object[]. I need to do the same thing in VB6, and I need the two to match exactly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sincerely doubtful.  Binary serialization is not guaranteed to be compatible between versions of .NET let alone back to VB 6.  XML serialization might be able to help you here.

Answer (score 1):

Create a COM visible DLL in C# and call it from VB6 when you need to serialize.

Comment: You then have to convert it to .tlb if I'm not mistaken.